# DoubleAnimation of Width does not shrink

Tags: xaml, animation

I am doing DoubleAnimation of the Width property of a Canvas. I want to shrink the canvas to 1/5 th of the size.

```
var widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
widthAnimation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
StoryBoard.SetTarget(widthAnimation, Canvas1);
StoryBoard.SetTargetProperty(widthAnimation, new PropertyPath("Width"));
widthAnimation.From = Canvas1.Width;
widthAnimation.To = Canvas1.Width * .2;

StoryBoard stb = new StoryBoard();
stb.Children.Add(widthAnimation);
stb.Begin();
```

Somehow, the above animation does not shrink the size to 1/5th. Instead, it enlarges the canvas. Any clues why the animation is doing something funny?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas was wrapped in a viewbox. The Viewbox size was fixed, while the canvas within it shrinked. The text expanded. Not sure why. But, I fixed the problem by applying the animation to the Viewbox rather than the Canvas. And it works all fine now.